# redirecting web from http to https - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: redirect, ssl

I have installed URL rewrite extension module in IIS and i would like to redirect a web app from http to https.
    The question is with sharepoint urls will this work accordingly as I have been reading different opinions on this.
Any tips would be appreciated or anyone have done this with successes?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: SharePoint web application should be configured as 1) SSL and 2) listening to HTTPS (443).

Comment: Thanks Boland I know that but my question was relating to redirecting

Comment: have you test it? any issue so far? http://blog.cellenza.com/archi-patterns-bp/reverse-proxy-iis-url-rewrite/ another method using AAM redirection http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fabdulwahab/archive/2013/01/21/configure-ssl-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It should work just fine, redirect is just one-timer whenever someone accesses site over HTTP, and it shouldn't even get to SharePoint, but happen in IIS. After redirect to identical address at HTTPS, user will continue browsing on SSL site. You need to ensure that in AAM you have configured internal and external address as HTTPS.

Only exception is if you're terminating SSL on load balancer, then you define external address as HTTPS and internal as HTTP.